# How to convert array of numpy arrays to csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, export-to-csv

How to convert an array of NumPy arrays to a CSV file.
I have mentioned the code below:

```
array_of_nparray = [[[1,2,3,4]],[[5,6,7,8]],[[9,10,11,12]]]
header = ["a","b","c","d"]
```

to a csv format:

```
a | b | c | d|
1 | 2 | 3 | 4|
5 | 6 | 7 | 8|
9 | 10 | 11 | 12|
```

I tried to do it with

```
with open("abc.csv","w") as f:
   m = csv.writer(f)
   m.writer(header)
   m.writerow(array_of_nparray)

But was unsuccessful because it printed all the NumPy arrays in the first column
Can anyone please help
```

Comment: This is not an array of numpy arrays: `array_of_nparray = [[[1,2,3,4]],[[5,6,7,8]],[[9,10,11,12]]]` It is a 3D nested list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

array_of_nparray = [[[1,2,3,4]],[[5,6,7,8]],[[9,10,11,12]]]
header = ["a","b","c","d"]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(array_of_nparray).reshape((3,4)), columns=header)

df.to_csv("file_name.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

By converting the array into pandas Dataframe and then saving it to CSV format.

```
import pandas as pd

array_of_nparray = [[[1,2,3,4]],[[5,6,7,8]],[[9,10,11,12]]]
header = ["a","b","c","d"]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(array_of_nparray).reshape((3,4)), columns=header)

df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [numpy.savetext](https://thispointer.com/how-to-save-numpy-array-to-a-csv-file-using-numpy-savetxt-in-python/) example, I got the following solution:

```
import numpy as np
array_of_nparray = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]])
header = ' a, b, c, d'
np.savetxt('2darray.csv', array_of_nparray, delimiter=',', header=header ,fmt='%d', comments='')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use simple string formatting too:

```py
array_of_nparray = [[[1,2,3,4]],[[5,6,7,8]],[[9,10,11,12]]]
header = ["a","b","c","d"]

with open("abc.csv","w") as f:
   f.write('#'+','.join(header)+'\n')
   for line in array_of_nparray:
       f.write(','.join([str(i) for i in line[0]])+'\n')
```

which, however has to be adapted to the different situations.